# How to SSH into to different VMs on the same MacOS?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have two virtual machines with UTM (the mac software. Similar to VirtualBox). The first one works perfectly. I can SSH and communicate between my mac and the VM via the terminal.

But for some reason, the second VM which is setup in the exact same way, is not allowing SSH.

They both have the same IP address.

I tried:

1. Removing the known hosts from my mac. No luck
2. checking if SSH is setup on VM2. It is.

Am I doing something wrong here? I am not sure how to begin the troubleshooting of this.

Thanks

Comment: `They both have the same IP address.` How is the ssh client / VM host supposed to differentiate them then?

Comment: How are the VMs configured, and how does VM networking work in UTM and/or macOS? That is, do the VMs get IP addresses via DHCP directly from your LAN router (bridged network), or do they get IP addresses from UTM/macOS (like "NAT network" in VirtualBox), or is the IP address configured statically within the VM?

Comment: @TomYan - I agree. the honest answer is changing IP addresses is beyond my skill. I cannot find anything on how to do that in UTM or any docs

Comment: its clear that i need to learn a bit more about how IPs work. thank you for you help.

Comment: In the preferences of UTM and/or the settings of the VMs there should (hopefully) be a "Network" section. If you could share with us what is there (screenshot or whatever), we may help...